# How to use Moq with Entity Framework IDbSet Count() etc. methods

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unit-testing, moq

I'm trying to use `Moq` to make some tests for Entity Framework Code First classes. I'm very new to Moq and mocking techniques and I wonder if it's possible to easily do a test that I will describe below. I searched through the web for some solutions, but most are based on repository pattern, which I want to avoid.

I have `ITestEntities` interface for context

```
public interface ITestEntities
{
    IDbSet<Order> Orders { get; }
    IDbSet<Product> Products { get; }
    IDbSet<User> Users { get; }
}
```

Then context

```
public class TestEntities : DbContext, ITestEntities
{
    public TestEntities() : base("name=TestEntities")
    {

    }

    public virtual IDbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public virtual IDbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public virtual IDbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

A controller and an action to test

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private ITestEntities db;

    public HomeController()
    {
        db = new TestEntities();
    }

    public HomeController(ITestEntities db)
    {
        this.db = db;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var count = db.Users.Count();
        ViewBag.count = count;

        return View(count);
    }        
}
```

And finally a NUnit test using Moq

```
[Test]
public void ModelValueShouldBeTwo()
{
    var mockUsers = new Mock<IDbSet<User>>();
    mockUsers.Setup(m => m.Count()).Returns(2);

    var mockDB = new Mock<ITestEntities>();
    mockDB.Setup(db => db.Users).Returns((IDbSet<User>)mockUsers);

    var controller = new HomeController((ITestEntities)mockDB);

    var view = controller.Index();

    Assert.IsInstanceOf<ViewResult>(view);
    Assert.AreEqual(((ViewResult)view).Model, 2);
}
```

The problem is with this line: `mockUsers.Setup(m => m.Count()).Returns(2);`. When running this test I get following error:

`System.NotSupportedException : Expression references a method that does not belong to the mocked object: m => m.Count<User>()`

I think this is due to `.Count()` being a static method so it cannot be mocked by Moq. Is there a way to test this simple action using Moq and not using full-fledged repository pattern, which as I understand should anyway have this `.Count()` part hardcoded into some method to be testable... Maybe I just use the mocks in a wrong way? Because I have impression that this should be quite simple and possible with EF Code First.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are mocking the test entities you don't need to mock any further down the chain

Something like this should do (although, I 'm not at an IDE so may need some tweaking)

**Update to include new InMemoryDbSet**

```
[Test]
public void ModelValueShouldBeTwo()
{
    //Build test users
    var mockUsers = new InMemoryDbSet<User>(){ new User(), new User()};
    var mockDB = new Mock<ITestEntities>();
    //Set up mock entities to returntest users.
    mockDB.Setup(db => db.Users).Returns(mockUsers);

    var controller = new HomeController((ITestEntities)mockDB);

    var view = controller.Index();

    Assert.IsInstanceOf<ViewResult>(view);
    Assert.AreEqual(((ViewResult)view).Model, 2);
}
```

This will mean the extension methods will simply work off of the test data you have supplied.

See below for a good article on mocking dbset
http://geekswithblogs.net/Aligned/archive/2012/12/12/mocking-or-faking-dbset.aspx

Comment: Note: This doesn't work for Async queries. See the official EF docs for a solution for that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314429.aspx#async

Answer (score 1):

**Mock `GetEnumerator()` instead of `Count()`**

`Count()` is an extension method on objects that implement `IEnumerable<T>`, and `IDbSet<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`

Extension methods are passed the object that they are called on. In this case the signature is:

```
public static int Count<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,  //This is your IDbSet that you are mocking
    Func<TSource, bool> predicate
)
```

Rather than trying to setup `Count()` to return a specific value, you can setup the members of `IEnumerable<T>` to achieve the same result. In the case of `IEnumerable<T>` all you have to do is set up `GetEnumerator()` to return an `Enumerator<T>` that enumerates over two values.

In this situation I usually create that `Enumerator<T>` by creating a new List with a couple of items and calling `GetEnumerator()` on it:

```
mockUsers.Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(new List<Users> {
    new User(),
    new User()
}.GetEnumerator());
```

Now, of course this effectively tests the extension method `Count()` in addition to whatever you are trying to achieve with your test, while that is a pretty low risk when the extension method is a part of .NET, it is something to keep in mind if you are using and authoring extension methods of your own.

Comment: This works for some kinds of queries against an `IDbSet`, but not all of them, for example `FirstOrDefault()` which doesn't use the enumerable weirdly.